# Using an if statement within a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm making an application that loads and displays various `.x3d` files in C# which I've already loaded into the project. I'm wondering if there's a way that I can have an `if statement` within the combo boxes. I want to have it so all the `.x3d` files from `Area1` are displayed if it's clicked, or all the models in `Model4` being displayed if selected.

The code that I have so far is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(comboBox1_SelectionChanged)
        {

        }
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

My thinking behind this is that it'll be if `Area1` is clicked, display all `.x3d` models that are associated with `Area1` else if `Area2` is clicked, display all that are associated with `Area2`. And the same for the second combo box too.

**UPDATE**

I've made some changes to the code within the combo boxes which are shown below

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {

        }
}
```

However when putting this in, I have an error in the `if` statement which says `The name 'comboBox1' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your method you can check the selected index of the combobox then deciding from there on.
In this case I'm looking into the first item in your combobox. That could be area1. Then in your if block you can do your other stuff.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(combobox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem that I have now is that it's saying that 'The name 'combobox1' does not exist in the current context' and I've changed it to 'comboBox1' and it still has the same error

Comment: Well ,if your combobox is named 'comboBox1', you should also write comboBox1.SelectedIndex. C# is case sensitive so you've to pay attention to such small things. Also, try to call controls by 'this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex', so these mistakes wont happen again :)

Comment: I have done it as 'comboBox1', I've even copied it from the 'private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged' bit and still has the error :/

Comment: Could you edit your code to show me, what you've done exactly?

Comment: So, you can try when working with visual studio - 'this.' just write into the if statement `if(this.)`    then some options will popup like your controls your methods. Go look through this list and find your combobox by name. When your combobox doesn't show up, you're missing something else.

Comment: Thanks. It's all sorted now :)

Comment: Would appreciate if you give me a "This answer is useful!" :)